# Trying to decompile a java .class file with javap.exe

Tags: java, decompiler, javap

I have some .class files that I want to decompile. So this is what I do:
 `javap -c "C:\users\Richard\workspace\pruebas\bin\ClassName"` and all the time I have the same error `ERROR:Could not find C:\users\Richard\workspace\pruebas\bin\ClassName`

However, if I list the files contained in such directory using the dir command I can see it listed.

Do you guys have any idea of what might be the cause? I did man javap and as far as I know the syntax is correct.

Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: not sure what the issue is but why not try a simple windows one with gui like JD ?

Comment: I don't know javap but usually you pass the fully qualified name of the class you are dealing with, not the full path. The program later finds the file by searching the class in its classpath

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`javap` looks for classes in the classpath. So, assuming that your ClassName is in the default package, invoke like this:

```
javap -c -classpath "C:\users\Richard\workspace\pruebas\bin" ClassName
```